# Input string was not in a correct format. Conversion from string "Normal" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql, arrays, vb.net

Im creating a multiple choice question and user choose the answer from radiobutton. After user chose the answer, it will be stored into array myArr.

How to store the answerId as integer as result in resultdetail table? I run this code and error " Input string was not in a correct format ".

```
Dim myArr(3) As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From view_Question Where QuestionID=@IdQuestion", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdQuestion", Counter)
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr1.Read() Then
        Me.lblQuestion.Text = dr1("QuestionTxt")
        Me.RadioButton1.Text = dr1("1")
        myArr(0) = dr1("1")
        Me.RadioButton2.Text = dr1("2")
        myArr(1) = dr1("2")
        Me.RadioButton3.Text = dr1("3")
        myArr(2) = dr1("3")
        Me.RadioButton4.Text = dr1("4")
        myArr(3) = dr1("4")

        Dim answerId As String

        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            answerId = myArr(0)
            Dim answer As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(answerId)
            Session("jaw") = answerId
        ElseIf Me.RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            answerId = myArr(1)
            Dim answer As Integer = CInt(answerId)
            Session("jaw") = answerId
        ElseIf Me.RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
            answerId = myArr(2)
            Dim answer As Integer = CInt(answerId)
            Session("jaw") = answerId
        ElseIf Me.RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
            answerId = myArr(3)
            Dim answer As Integer = CInt(answerId)
            Session("jaw") = answerId
        End If

        'Dim answer As Integer = CInt(answerId)
        'Session("jaw") = answerId

    Else
        conn.Close()
        Counter += 1
        soalan()
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Pardon me, but even experts probably can't glance at your code and determine what the problem is without a little help from you. To begin with, tell us what line the problem occurs on.

Comment: what is the correct answer for "what line is the error on?"

Comment: Briefly, the error message is fairly clear: `Normal` is not a valid integer. So don't try to convert it to an integer.

Comment: error for both Dim answer As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(answerId) and im answer As Integer = CInt(answerId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the text of the answer back from the datareader; that just doesn't translate to the ID; you have to query the ID as well.  Or by answer ID do you mean 1, 2, 3, 4?  If that is the case, just hard-code it based on the radio button checked:

```
 If Me.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
     answerId = 1 ' since first radio is checked
     Dim answer As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(answerId)
     Session("jaw") = answerId
```

Comment: it cannot be hard-code because all i wanna do i pass the ID from the answer table into answer detail table. if i use hard-code answerId = 1 it will simply pass the number 1 into the table while each answer has it own id

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but in the code above, dr("1") has what, the text or the ID?  Where does the ID come from, because both this one field appears to be used for two different purposes...

Comment: since it was extract from a view, the 1,2,3,4 is the name of the column in the view for randomize answer selection. so basically there is one table to store answer directory and a view to randomize the answer for each question